# Basic http authentication on the <audio> tag?

Tags: http, audio, html5-audio, basic-authentication

Basically I want to do this

```
        <audio controls="controls" src="http://default:pwd@192.168.0.124:7906/audio/external_id/local-1348240572-1889941832?bitrate=320">           Your browser does not support the HTML5 Audio element.      </audio>
```

But its not working because I think you can't do authentication by doing something like user:pwd@example.com on browsers anymore.

Are there a simple way to use a source that requires basic authentication on the audio tag?

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of having authentication in the first place if the user can just Inspect the code and find the username and password?

Comment: The thing is, I didn't make the server software. If I made the server and know how to modify things I would just remove the authentication

Comment: @M Isa what server software are you using??

Comment: the software is MusikCube, it's a music player but it has a music streaming client for Android, but as far as I know they don't have a streaming client for desktop. You can remove the password for authentication and that might allow me to get the audio without authentication but that would remove the password for the entire server and I want it to be slightly secure.

Comment: And the api documentation looks pretty simple so I thought I could try to make a client with some html and js

Comment: Also, the user would have to input their own username and password so it's not going to be visible to anyone except to someone that already have access to the username and password